# using angularjs router instead spring mvc router

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, angularjs-routing

im using spring mvc with angular js.
i would like to know if there's a way to use angularjs router instead 
using spring mvc router?

//Java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "cases", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showCase() {
    return "case/cases";
}


//angular
app.angular.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        controller : 'UserController',
        templateUrl : 'login.html'
    }).when('/case', {
        controller : 'CaseController',
        templateUrl : 'case/cases.html',
     })

} ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use angularjs routing features, you need to design restful api with spring. Your controllers should return json data that can be easily consumed by angularjs.

Comment: Thank you! do i need to map the view in java controller?@RequestMapping(value = "cases", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showCase() {
    return "case/cases";
}

Comment: You will need to map requests to your controller (through  [@RequestMapping]) and you would not be returning view names. You should probably look at [@RestController] and [@ResponseBody] annotations for more information. Also have a look at the spring io guide http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: I'll always get error 404 on browser but when i map the view names in java controller it works.